# Java-generated PDF renders fine on screen, but does not print correctly

Tags: java, pdf, printing, itext

I'm generating a complex PDF from a swing application by printing my JComponent.

This PDF is created by getting a proxy Graphics2D object from an iText PdfTemplate object.

The PDF is viewable on-screen, but when printed in banner mode on a Lexmark 4650 from windows printing cuts off after the fourth page, with most items not being printed.

Is there a good way to look at the contents of the PDF to see if something is out of line? The PDF seems to be larger than it needs to be, given the information it contains.

Or, a way to get a useful error from the Lexmark printer?

[Download the PDF File](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6466134/StackOverflow%20PDF%202.pdf)

**EDIT 2011-10-18 13:45:00 PST**: replaced PDF with a smaller version with less PDF shape data. Still not printing correctly.

Here is the output from the printer. You can see that printout cuts off shortly after the 410 depth.

[image: PDF Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a rendering issue where a line was being drawn to a coordinate of Integer.MIN_VALUE, this made the printer very unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen printing fail when there is not enough memory - printing needs a much bigger raster than screen. Does increasing memory help?

Comment: Thanks mark, We are actually printing the PDF from Adobe Reader, not directly from Java. Java is only used to generate the PDF, not send it to the printer. I don't think it's a memory issue.